# array convert into Magento 2 collection

Tags: magento2, product, collection, array, convert

I have 2 collection 1 is $bestsalecollection that show in dashboard . second is product collection. 
After filter collection when i return it generate error **Call to a member function isLoaded() on array**

Please any one help me to tell **how filter array convert into magento collection ?**

Thank you

```
 $bestsalecollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class
            )->addStoreFilter(
                $storeId
            );
            $productCollection = $this->productcollectionFactory->create();
            $sellercollection=$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('current_user_id',array('eq'=>1));
            $filter_product=[];

            foreach ($sellercollection as $allProduct){
                foreach ($bestsalecollection as $bestSale){
                    if($allProduct->getEntityId()==$bestSale->getProductId()){
                        $filter_product[]=$bestSale;
                    }
                }
            }
    $this->setCollection($filter_product);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject Magento\Framework\Data\CollectionFactory in constructor for `$this->collectionFactory`

```
$bestsalecollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->setModel(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::class
        )->addStoreFilter(
            $storeId
        );

        $productCollection = $this->productcollectionFactory->create();
        $sellercollection=$productCollection->addFieldToFilter('current_user_id',array('eq'=>1));
        $filter_product=$this->collectionFactory->create();

        foreach ($sellercollection as $allProduct){
            foreach ($bestsalecollection as $bestSale){
                if($allProduct->getEntityId()==$bestSale->getProductId()){
                    $varienObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
                    $varienObject->setData($bestSale->getData());
                    $filter_product->addItem($varienObject);
                }
            }
        }
    $this->setCollection($filter_product);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
```

Comment: `$this->setCollection($filter_product);`   is not usefull ?

Comment: It can also be used. But for that also, use need to create that variable as collection factory and push product array using addItem before set collection

Comment: Have you tried above method?did you get any error?

Comment: Sir i am confuse where you setCollection() ?

Comment: If you want to create your own custom collection then setCollection can be used..

Comment: Sir   `$collection->addItem($varienObject);`  ?
where is $collection varibale define ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93857/discussion-between-hafiz-umer-and-aravind).

Comment: Sir i tried your code but now error is 

 `Illegal offset type in /var/www/html/codility-magento-market-place/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 76`

i am open DataObject.php file on line 76 it setData() method

Comment: Sir i did this by changes in 2 line . 

`$varienObject->setData($bestSale->getData());`

`$this->setCollection($filter_product);`

Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome,Sorry for not providing the exact solution..

Comment: Sir you provide me 99.9% answer . Thanks alot Sir

Comment: You update the answer with your code..I will accept that answer